# Find one <a> tag and remove text

Tags: jquery

I have the following code.

http://jsfiddle.net/CtMmT/4/

Now i need to remove the text from the  tag where you can find the "Google must dissappear" text

The output for that row must be

```
<a title="" href="http://www.google.com"></a>.
```

I tried to select the a tag , but i can't get only that 1  tag.
I get always, all the a tags .
I tried with the following each loops.
But not with any result.

I can't set any class on that  tag to control so that is not an option.

```
$('ul.menu li.dhtml-menu').each(function() {


}); 

$('ul.menu li.dhtml-menu a').each(function() {


});
```

Comment: What property of that specific tag indicates that it needs to be deleted - is it just the text between the opening and closing `<a>` tags? Its position? In other words, what are you searching for to differentiate that tag from the others?

Comment: in a concrete example you will not have an id/class something to recognize this anchor?

Comment: No there is no id/class on that <a> tag to recognize the anchor. I need to remove this because the text must change in some picture. The picure is already set with css. But the text must be deleted.

Comment: please do not add superfluous tags. If this is strictly about jquery no one needs to know this is part of a php/drupal project, so no need to add tags for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're just looking to remove the inner text of the anchor tag, you'll need to loop through all the anchor tags in your `div`, and check their `text()` value.

jQuery:

```
$('#content a').each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() == 'Google Must disappear')
        $(this).text('');
});
```

Working example on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KFEVv/).

**Edit for OP's comment:** Since you're looking to manipulate an element based on the structure, rather than the inner text, I strongly recommend reworking your markup so that it is valid first. As your markup is right now, nesting a `li` directly inside an `li` is causing Firefox to close the first `li` tag:
[image: bad markup]

I would change the markup first, rather than writing some jQuery to deal with this tag soup.

Comment: Correct, just one thing to notice - setting inner text/HTML to empty will remove the `<a>` completely, see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/CtMmT/19/) how to still have it (with changed text) and disable the click event.

Comment: @SedatBaşar using jQuery selectors will do exactly the same behind the scenes, so yes - this *is* good answer.

Comment: Shorter version, same functionality: _$('#content a:contains(Google Must disappear)').text('');_

Comment: @Shadow Wizard yes u are rigth but no need to loop for all 'a' elements. Need just a selector for it. It will be enaugh. If dont use jquery selectors, what is the meaning of use jquery? So not a good answer

Comment: The OP is asking to select based on the inner text of the element, so yes, you do need to loop through all anchor tags. Besides, under the hood, jQuery is going to loop through all the tags to evaluate the attribute selector anyways. Also, setting the inner text to the empty string **does not** remove the element from the DOM, you just can't see it.

Comment: Also, contains is certainly not the same as equality for strings.

Comment: @SedatBaşar that's just [syntactic sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar).

Comment: It's not always the same text. It's just in this example the text "Google Must dissapear" that must go away. It's just always the text on the a tag under the li.dhtml-menu that must dissapear.

Comment: What about for something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31277497/how-to-remove-text-which-isnt-inside-an-anchor-link-from-a-table-cell

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
$('ul.menu a').each(function() {
  if($(this).html() == "Google Must disappear")
      $(this).html("");
});
```

Comment: Better use `.text()` - what if the anchor contains HTML of its own?

Comment: You're right, but I was just trying to know if that's what he was looking for, because I couldn't understand well the question.

Comment: It's not always the same text. It's just in this example the text "Google Must dissapear" that must go away. It's just always the text on the a tag under the li.dhtml-menu that must dissapear.

Comment: Now I get what you mean SvenVdb, it's weird that only takes the a tag that is "deeper" in the DOM. Updated example to see what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/CtMmT/22/

Comment: I don't get it! The text between <a> </a> on row 7 in your last example must be removed. Nothing else. :) The link and text is every time different.

Comment: I found the problem.. the a tag with the text "Google Must dissapear", his parent is the <ul class="menu"> not the <li id="dhtml_menu-759" class="dhtml-menu">. You can see what I mean in the example: http://jsfiddle.net/CtMmT/26/

Answer (score 0):

i still do not understand what you are talking about, but if you want select some node, you can specify it a `id`.

like:

```
<a href="http://google.com" id="googleLink">Google</a>
```

and select it by

```
 $("#googleLink")
```

otherwise, you can use the [child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) in jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a div around it and hide it.

http://jsfiddle.net/mR2Ts/

```
    <div id='content'>
<ul class="menu">
    <li id="dhtml_menu-759" class="dhtml-menu">
        <li class="leaf dhtml-menu-cloned-leaf">
            <a title="" href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
        </li> 
        <div id="hide-this">
        <a title="" href="http://www.google.com">Google Must disappear</a>
            </div>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li id="dhtml_menu-760" class="dhtml-menu">
                <a href="http://www.microsoft.com">Microsoft</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
    <a href="#hide-this" class="close">Clicking here will hide the link</a>
</div>


$(function() {
$('a.close').click(function() {
    $($(this).attr('href')).slideUp();
    return false;
});
```

});

Comment: I can't add some div arround that <a> tag

Comment: Then you can just give the a an id... 

edited jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/mR2Ts/2/

Comment: I also can't add some id to it.